# Is it possible to perform a command on string stored inside a variable?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Hi I'm currently trying to execute the following code. I have stored a string inside the variable DATE which is in the format YYYY/MM/DD. Im trying to extract the year by using the cut command. I receive an error stating it is not a file or directory. Is there a modification I could make or a different way of doing it?

```
for file in ~/filesToSort/*
do

   DATE=$(head -1 $file | tr "-" "/")
   echo "${DATE}"
   YYYY=$(cut -c1-4 accounts $DATE)
   #echo "${YYYY}"
done
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the first line of every file in `~/filesToSort/*` a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cut` utility reads data from its standard input stream, it does not operate on strings given as arguments.

To use `cut`, therefore, you need to pass the data on standard input:

```bsh
YYYY=$( printf '%s\n' "$DATE" | cut -d '/' -f 1 )
```

However, that would be very slow in a loop.  Instead, use a built-in parameter substitution to delete everything after the first `/` in the `$DATE` string:

```bsh
YYYY=${DATE%%/*}
```

This removes the longest suffix string from `$DATE` that matches the shell pattern `/*`.  If the string is `2021/10/21`, then this returns `2021`.

To get the first four characters of every file in a directory (which is the essence of what I *believe* your current code is attempting to do), you could use `sed` like so:

```
for name in "$HOME"/filesToSort/*; do
    sed -e 's/\(....\).*/\1/' -e q "$name"
done
```

This reads in the first line of each file, replaces the contents of the line with the first four characters of the line, and then quits after outputting the result to the terminal.

Comment: This is the kind of stuff I _really_ need to learn

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way using the good ole `awk`

```bsh
for file in *; do
    awk -F'-' 'NR==1 {print $1}' $file
done
```

- `-F '-'` tells awk to use the `-` as the delimiter
- `NR==1` tell awk to read the first line of every file only
- `{print $1}` only print the first field separated by the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

If your shell supports it, you can use Here Strings (`<<<`) for this. From `man bash`:

```
Here Strings
       A variant of here documents, the format is:

              [n]<<<word

       The word undergoes tilde expansion, parameter and variable  expansion,
       command  substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.  Path‐
       name expansion and word splitting are not performed.   The  result  is
       supplied  as  a single string, with a newline appended, to the command
       on its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).
```

In your case, you would do:

```
for file in ~/filesToSort/*
do

   date=$(head -1 "$file" | tr "-" "/")
   echo "${DATE}"
   yyy=$(cut -c1-4 <<< "$date")
   echo "$yyy"
done
```